# Comparing cells with using Excel LEFT Function

Tags: excel

I wanted to compare value in cell A1 and B1.
However, sometimes PC give different value as cell B1.

[image]

Initial code I've been writing is as below in cell C1:
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$5,0)),"","Duplicate")

This code only compare exact value. Thus, I'm trying to add LEFT Function into function above:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Left(A1,8),$B$1:$B$5,0)),"","Duplicate")

But above function only count character in A1 only. How do I add LEFT(B1,8) to also read value in cell B1?

Thanks.

Regards,
Zaiem

Comment: a quick hack might be to have column C be LEFT(B,8) then do your formula in column D

Comment: But isn't your formula working right now? Or do you mean you also have more characters in column B?

Comment: @Jerry thanks. I think I got it now.

Comment: @Jerry My formula is working right now, just I don't know how to insert LEFT Function in my initial function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean add _another_ left?

Comment: @Jerry No, I meant something like this  =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT(A1,8),LEFT($B$1:$B$5,8),0)),"","Duplicate")   But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you would like is:

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(FIND(LEFT(A$1,8),B$1:B$5),""))=1,"Duplicate","")
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>